# XML exception on loading

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file. When I try to load it using .LOAD methods, I get this exception:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: data at root level invalid at position 1 line 1.
```

What I have at the beginning of the XML file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to load a file using `LoadXml()` or trying to `Load()` and passing it an XML string?

Comment: It could be later in the file and the error reported is not so useful.

Comment: LoadXml(xmlString) is what I am trying. what could be the problem?? I read somewhere that this could be due to Encoding

Comment: Can you show more of your XML structure as it might be the content following the header.

Comment: @user424294 Yes, this could easily be due to encoding - you can try re-saving the offending XML file in a Unicode format (which shouldn't cause any problems) to confirm that encoding is the culprit.

Comment: can you paste the xml file that causes the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pouring in your suggestions. The problem was on the build server, the XML file was being pulled from a field called contents in a table called File. I am accessing the XML using the FileID. But the FileID is not the same as FileID on my local database. So, On the build server, I was pulling the XML from a test record which had dummy data. Hence the error. Hope I have made sense. I have fixed the issue by dynamically finding the FileID and querying the contents.

Answer (score 3):

I think that string that is used for LoadXml is constructed wrong by either

- ignoring BOM and forcing wrong encoding
- reading BOM as first character
- constructed by hand altogether and first character is not `<`

Based on last comment I bet that code looks like (or some variation of it) instead of loading XML directly from Stream object (which will handle encoding properly):

```
    // My guess of how wrong code looks like! Not a solution!!!!
    StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
    string xml = r.ReadToEnd();
    XmlDocument d = new XmlDocument();
    d.LoadXml(xml);
```

You should review your code that constructs the string you are using in XmlDocument.LoadXml and check if it is indeed valid XML. I'd recommend to create small program that models code that is failing and investigate the behavior.

Comment: This is the exact code:  /// <summary>
        ///  <para>Loads a DataMap with the xml passed by using a XmlDataDocument for loading
        ///     the xml. This supports the use of entity references in the xml.</para>
        /// </summary>
        public static DataMap CreateDataMapFromXml(string xmlData)
        {
            DataMap dm = new DataMap();
            XmlDataDocument dt = new XmlDataDocument(dm);

            dt.LoadXml(xmlData);

            return dm;
        }

Comment: This is the first few exact XMl: <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> <DataMap xmlns="http://www.api.com/data/DataMap">

Comment: Also, I am constrcting the XML in an notepad and saving it as xml. Do you think that could make some difference.

Comment: Consider editing original post with these details next time... Are you sure that xmlData[0] is '<'? Debug the code and double check it please.

Comment: Okay as per your suggestion, this is what I have done:  string xml = File.ReadAllText(item.FullName);
                Console.WriteLine(" The first character is {0}", xml.Substring(0,1));
                Console.ReadLine();

Comment: And the first character is "<".

Comment: To add to whatever I have mentioned, I am able to get this work on the local machine. It fails for me on the build server. I am clueless on what the problem is.  Can I send the XML file to anyone so that anybody can take a look at it. I can't post the entire XML here even if I want to.

Comment: Noone here except you can debug your code that fails and see why the string you are passing to CreateDataMapFromXml function is not valid XML. If you can't debug on that server - trace first several characters of that string to a log (I assume you have some sort of logging working) and see if you find something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Position 1 line 1 suggests a problem with the very first char it encounters.

I would suggest firstly confirming that no leading whitespace/other char is in there (sounds silly, but they can creep in easily).

It could also be a char encoding issue, causing that first char to not be read as a '<'.

Comment: i checked for white spaces. assuming that it is not the problem, how do we fix the encoding issue.

Comment: You could try opening the file in notepad, then "Save As" ... and select "Ansi" encoding.  Then recheck the first char is still '<'.

Comment: @user - you need to provide more details (call stack and preferably first several bytes of the XML in question) to anyone to provide more details. @Chris Rogers - Utf8 is default encoding for XML, so it is unclear what you mean as "does not support".

Comment: @Alexei - Yes, you're correct. My memory was faulty on that point. That part has been removed.  Though it still may be an encoding issue.  Saving to a known encoding and then specifying that in the xml header (UTF-8 by default) could be something to try.

Comment: This is the stack trace :    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
     at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
     at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
     at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
     at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
     at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
     at System.Xml.XmlDataDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
     at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)

Comment: Perhaps this can provide better insight into the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's not there. I've found that when I've gotten this error the file or path is missing/incorrect.